# I am trying to make a drum rotate with water fluid

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am trying to make a drum rotate with water fluid. I'm looking for a clear explanation of effector and domain.

Effector fails to fill in the shape.

I just want to fill a horizontal cylinder with water and rotate with dynamics.

I'm using Blender 2.9

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the 
bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add 
more information on how you set up your project.
[Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that 
might help us understand your scene and settings. See [How to upload 
an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491). 
Consider sharing your .blend file so that others can inspect it. You 
can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then 
paste the resulting link as part of your question.